# How does System.out.println() work in a thread?

Tags: java

I have a question about how the System class works.

Lets say there is a server which creates a thread for each client that connects to it, and a thread calls System.out.println(message) at some point. Which computer will have that message printed out? Is it the server's computer or the client computer? Does it matter which side created the thread?

Comment: is this question really being asked...?

Comment: yes i needed the peace of mind to make sure i was not making a careless assumption

Comment: You'd be surprised how often this comes up, @user1329572 (how do I make my PHP execute in the browser directly? Why does my server have a bunch of messageboxes up?)

Comment: This is not a question about 'how the `System` class works'. It is a question about what `System.out` *is.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which computer will have that message printed out? Is it the server's computer or the client computer?

It will be on the server.

> Does it matter which side created the thread?

It's impossible for the client to create a thread on the server (and vice-versa). The *server* can create new threads in response to connections from the client, but that's totally different.

Simply put: If the code is running on the server, `System.out` outputs on the server unless someone overrides normal behavior via [`setOut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) and implements a `PrintStream` that outputs via a socket stored in local thread storage. And they won't, it would be a nutso thing to do. :-)

Comment: Sorry to bother, I have a quick question about clients not being able to create threads. If I have a server and a client, and the client needs to do run through two simultaneous loops of checking something (like checking for user input and server input) can I create a thread in that sense for the client?

Comment: @CowZow - a client cannot create a thread on the server ... but it CAN create a thread locally (i.e. on the client) ... assuming that the client is implemented in a language that supports threads.  (Javascript doesn't ...)

Comment: It will be on the console of the JVM that contains the instance of System.out. Clients and servers have nothing to do with it whatsoever.

Comment: @StephenC: JavaScript can be multi-threaded if the environment supports it. [Most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) do, for instance, via [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/). It's true that there aren't any **language** features that support it, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relationship between threads on a server and threads on some client that talks to it. There is no relationship between System.out on a server and anything on any client that happens to talk to it. The effect of sending something to System.out is (unless you redirect it) completely unrelated to whether the program is a client, server, or coat-hanger.

Answer (score 0):

Each `Thread` is created on the server's machine and runs on the server's machine. The `System.out` call will be printed on the server's machine.

Answer (score 0):

The server will print out; System.out.println is unaffected by the external conditions of the server-client its called from.